# How to set a variable used by the application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an ad list that needs to be displayed in all the pages of my site, so I added the list to the application layout. Something like this:

```
<div>
    <%= render @ads %>
<div>
```

I want the ad list to be retrieved from the db before the application layout is rendered, but not when another layout is used, so I guess that before_filter is not the solution, right?

Where should I put this code?

```
@ads = Ad.all
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the ads list should be displayed on every page of the site, then something like this should work:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :preload_ads


  private

  def :preload_ads
    @ads = Ad.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! But when another layout is rendered, the db query is performed too, right? I'm trying to find the optimal alternative in terms of performance.

Comment: If you  want the ads list on every page, you need to load it before each action, regardless of what layout is rendered.

Comment: Right, but I have for example another layout that I use internally for a service. I don't want the calls to this service to perform a useless db query.

Comment: Then one approach would perhaps be to organize your controllers somehow - the ApplicationController would be a parent for at least two child controllers, and the before filter would be in the one child that does the "normal" work (not the internal service work). Just an idea...

Answer (score 2):

Use [cell components](http://cells.rubyforge.org/) if you're looking for a testable and stable solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you're certain it's only going to be used in that single layout (and no other), you *can* just load it in the layout:

```
<div>
    <%= render Ad.all %>
<div>
```